# How can I open an .xps file in Evince?

Tags: 11.10, evince, xps-file

On [projects.gnome.org](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/) I read that [evince](http://packages.ubuntu.com/evince)/`Document Viewer` supports *xps*-files. But when I try to open an *xps*-file I get the error message

> **Unable to open document**
> File type Zip archive (application/zip) is not supported

Reading "the full list of supported document formats" on [live.gnome.org](http://live.gnome.org/Evince/SupportedDocumentFormats) I can't find *xps* there.

Now I ask myself (and you): Isn't `Document Viewer` able to open *xps*-files, or is there something wrong with that *xps*-file I try to open?

I specifically want to do this with Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.

---

I'd like to see a solution for `Evince` or Gnome in general, not get a recommendation for a KDE application like [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/5149/46531).

Comment: I'm interested if there is an answer - I've tried to recompile the latest evince under 11.10 - however the rerequisites breaks 11.10 (GTK, libpoppler etc) - therefore I'm doubtful that there is a 11.10 answer.  Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: If you have any problems with xpsto* command line tools, you should file a bug upstream to libgxps: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=libgxps - I maintain the ppa, I will *try* to upload the new 0.2.2 version of libgxps, maybe that fixes your issue. My test files worked fine: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libarchive/+bug/951139/+attachment/2845528/+files/xps-examples.zip

Comment: @medigeek - that really should be an answer!

Comment: @medigeek You are right, your test files work fine! So it seems to be a problem of that *xps* I created from a strange *pdf*. I can't upload these files, but you can try it [by yourself](http://www.diakonie-dresden.de/uploads/media/FORM-KTB-Voranmeldung_Eberswalderstrasse.pdf).

Comment: @fossfreedom Bruno's answer is enough, I didn't add any new ideas, since there's pretty much only one way to do it. :) Jakob, So you're trying to convert a pdf to an xps and then back to pdf? If so, I think the pdf you posted uses a new version (1.7) which is not supported by many applications. For example, I cannot open that pdf in evince: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/321720

Comment: @medigeek Thanks for the bug link - it looked exactly like this! When I saved the pdf I mentioned above it became saved with this stupid message ... That's why I "printed" an xps and then tried to re-convert to be usable in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, the problem is that for Ubuntu 11.10 the necessary library to open .xps files [was not included](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/375038) and at the moment there is no package for it.

This has apparently and possibly will be included by default in Ubuntu 12.04.

**You can add support to convert .xps files in to another format tough.** On the [packager's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~medigeek/+archive/evince-xps) you can read

> Note: The evince version in ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot doesn't work with xps (segmentation fault when opening the file) and there are several packages to be backported. I've decided not to backport it. It works in ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin.
>   **If you need to read an xps file, package libgxps-utils provides enough conversion tools, e.g. command: xpstopdf myfile.xps.**

That means that you can add the PPA to your system and at least convert your .xps to another format that can be opened in your system.

---

To do that add the PPA to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:medigeek/evince-xps
```

Update and install the necessary tools to convert your files

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgxps-utils
```

You will then be able to convert your .xps files in to another format as described in the PPA description

```
xpstopdf foo_file.xps
```

will convert a file called `foo_file.xps` in to a .pdf file.

---

For more information on PPAs and how to use them please have a look at any of these 2 posts

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: @Jakob Lets hope a better answer comes from here, does a _Use some other program_ answers look favorable to you?

Comment: @Jakob Understood, just wondering if this would become a dupe of the one you linked or if posted as an answer it would be worthy of the bounty.